# Rollback of bot migration is only available for one out of three bots

Tags: azure, botframework, azureportal, azure-bot-service

As many other owners of [Bot Framework bots](https://dev.botframework.com/bots) I was advised to "migrate MS Bot Framework bots to Azure". In documentation I also found information about [rollback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Bot-Framework/bot-service-migrate-bot#roll-back-migration)

In my case I ended up with three bots successfully migrated and working fine however only one of them offers rollback. And this behavior is persistent and independent to refresh and/or login/logout.

**What might have been different for affected bots to produce such result?**

Actual screenshot:

[image: actual state]

In [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) I can see rollback only for the same bot and the other two offer only "Delete"
[image: delete and rollback]

I started like this:

[image: initial state]

Comment: Have you checked out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-migrate-bot, Migration is currently enabled for registration bot types only. Migration for other types of Azure Bot Service (Preview) bots will be coming soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the article [Migrate your bot to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Bot-Framework/bot-service-migrate-bot):

> Migration is currently enabled for **registration bot types** only. Migration for SDK bots and Functions bots will be coming soon.

This means that only bot registrations can be migrated to the new Azure product called Bot Channels Registration.

There is also a note at the bottom which explains:

> Roll back functionality for registration bots is coming soon.

To summarize, currently only bot registrations can be migrated, but at the same time, bot registrations are not supported for rollback so there will be no button present.